# translate coordinates, then rotate coordinates in X and Y so Z' points at origin

Tags: coordinates, transform, wolfram-mathematica

I'd like to establish a matrix (either 4x4 or 3x3 to transform XYZ->X'Y'Z') that will translate my origin by {x,y,z} and then rotate the matrix so that the Z' axis points to the origin {X=0,Y=0,Z=0}

I've tried doing 2 rotations around arbitrary axes and then a translation independently, but once the coordinates are changed once, there are errors in the resulting position of my X'Y'Z' coordinate system

Comment: A translation requires the extra dimension, so 3x3 is out.  The problem has infinitely many answers (even for a non-zero translation) because of the freedom of azimuth as you look back at the origin; is there one in particular you want?

Comment: Sounds like a "lookAt" matrix.  [Here's](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_camera.html) a pretty helpful link.

Comment: The matrix is used to transform world coordinates XYZ to camera coordinates X'Y'Z'. The 2 rotations are done on the X and Y axis, so I don't think there is ambiguity.

Comment: @0x5453 , the link you sent is basically my application, I'm reading through it now to see if I can adapt it to Python or Mathematica

Comment: @0x5453 The link that you sent lookAt, seems to work only for 1 rotation, and then would not work for the second rotation...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this question by using 2 rotations around an arbitrary axis, and then the LookAt matrix from @0x5453. Attached is the code, where Mv is the final 4x4 matrix:

`def findWorld2Cam([x,y,z]):

```
#   EXTRINSIC
camtheta=np.arctan(location[0]/location[2])
T=np.eye(4)
T[0:3,3]=-location
u=[0,1,0]
theta=camtheta
Rtheta=np.array([[np.cos(theta) + u[0]**2* (1 - np.cos(theta)), 
   u[0]* u[1]* (1 - np.cos(theta)) - u[2]* np.sin(theta), 
   u[0] *u[2]* (1 - np.cos(theta)) + u[1]* np.sin(theta), 0],
  [u[1] *u[0]* (1 - np.cos(theta)) + u[2]* np.sin(theta), 
   np.cos(theta) + u[1]**2 *(1 - np.cos(theta)), 
   u[1] *u[2]* (1 - np.cos(theta)) - u[0] *np.sin(theta), 0],
  [u[2] *u[0]* (1 - np.cos(theta)) - u[1] *np.sin(theta), 
   u[2]* u[1] *(1 - np.cos(theta)) + u[0]* np.sin(theta), 
   np.cos(theta) + u[2]**2 *(1 - np.cos(theta)), 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]])
#u=np.dot(Rtheta,[1,0,0,1])
u=[1,0,0]
camphi=np.arctan(location[1]/location[2])
phi=-camphi
Rphi=np.array([[np.cos(phi) + u[0]**2* (1 - np.cos(phi)), 
   u[0]* u[1]* (1 - np.cos(phi)) - u[2]* np.sin(phi), 
   u[0] *u[2]* (1 - np.cos(phi)) + u[1]* np.sin(phi), 0],
  [u[1] *u[0]* (1 - np.cos(phi)) + u[2]* np.sin(phi), 
   np.cos(phi) + u[1]**2 *(1 - np.cos(phi)), 
   u[1] *u[2]* (1 - np.cos(phi)) - u[0] *np.sin(phi), 0],
  [u[2] *u[0]* (1 - np.cos(phi)) - u[1] *np.sin(phi), 
   u[2]* u[1] *(1 - np.cos(phi)) + u[0]* np.sin(phi), 
   np.cos(phi) + u[2]**2 *(1 - np.cos(phi)), 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]])
R=np.dot(Rphi,Rtheta)
up1=np.dot(R,[0,1,0,1])

theta=np.arctan(location[0]/location[2])
phi=np.arctan(location[1]/location[2])
l=[0,0,0]
Mt=np.eye(4)
F=l-location
Mt[0:3,3]=-location
forward=F/np.linalg.norm(F)
up=up1[0:3]/np.linalg.norm(up1[0:3])
left=np.cross(up,forward)
Mr=np.eye(4)
Mr[0,0:3]=left
Mr[1,0:3]=up
Mr[2,0:3]=forward
Mv=np.dot(Mr,Mt)
return Mv
`
```